# Swift/SwiftUI Trying to pass array from one view to another, which is falsely flagged as being nil

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I can't understand why my array (which I checked to ensure it isn't empty) is not being passed through to a view correctly.

ContentView receives the set of questions from MenuView, and once assigned to contentSelectedSet, I checked to make sure the two sets contained the correct information, which they do. The entire set of questions as I would expect is there. However, in the .fullScreenCover modifier, the set is not passed to DebugQuizView and will only take me to that else text. If I don't use the if/else block the app crashes.

I don't think the issue would be with MenuView passing in the array, because I have verified with the print statements that the value passed is correct, but I could have always missed something.

Further, I have tried directly passing in one of the quiz question arrays itself (avoiding the dependency on MenuView), and continue to run into the same problem.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isQuizViewShowing = false
//    @State var contentQuizTitle = ""
    @State var contentSelectedSet: [Question]?
    @State var hasSelectedSet = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            MenuView(onQuizButtonTapped: { menuSelectedSet in
                contentSelectedSet = menuSelectedSet
                hasSelectedSet = true
                print("The content set is \(String(describing: contentSelectedSet))")
                print("The selected set is \(menuSelectedSet)")
                isQuizViewShowing = true})
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "book.fill")
                    Text("Learn")
                }
            PracticeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "chart.bar.fill")
                    Text("Practice")
                }
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                    Text("Settings")
                }
        }

        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isQuizViewShowing) {
            if hasSelectedSet, let selectedSet = contentSelectedSet {
                DebugQuizView(
                    isPresented: $isQuizViewShowing,
//                    quizTitle: contentQuizTitle,
                    selectedSet: selectedSet
                )

            }
            else {
                Text("Selected set is nil") // show a message if selectedSet is nil
            }
        }

        }
}
```

Additionally if it helps, here is an example of the question that would be passed into ContentView from MenuView:

```
var questionsCore = [
    Question(text: "What is the capital of New Zealand?", options: ["What if one of the answer choices is a longer answer", "Christchurch", "Wellington", "Auckland"], correctAnswer: "Wellington", imageName: nil, originalOptions: ["What if one of the answer choices is a longer answer", "Christchurch", "Wellington", "Auckland"]),
    Question(text: "What is the highest mountain in New Zealand?", options: ["Mount Cook", "Mount Aspiring", "Mount Taranaki"], correctAnswer: "Mount Cook", imageName: UIImage(named: "cherry"), originalOptions: ["Mount Cook", "Mount Aspiring", "Mount Taranaki"]),
]
```

At first I thought it could have been an issue with the receiving view, but I made a new, empty one to check it and still receive the same issue there:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DebugQuizView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State var selectedSet: [Question]
    var body: some View {


        Text(selectedSet[1].text)
            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `item:` instead of `isPresented:`. Or add `[contentSelectedSet] in` to the beginning of the fullScreenCover closure.

Comment: The closure passed to `fullScreenCover` captures the variables when the view is created, not when `isQuizViewShowing` is set to `true`, so at the time the variable is captured, it is `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach, using a `ObservableObject` model class to hold
your `contentSelectedSet`, as shown in the example code. Works for me.

Why is using a simple `@State var contentSelectedSet: [Question]?` not working,
I don't know for sure, but @Paulw11 explanation seems to be correct.

```
struct Question: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var options: [String]
    var correctAnswer: String
    var imageName: UIImage?
    var originalOptions: [String]
    
    static var questionsCore = [
        Question(text: "What is the capital of New Zealand?", options: ["What if one of the answer choices is a longer answer", "Christchurch", "Wellington", "Auckland"], correctAnswer: "Wellington", imageName: nil, originalOptions: ["What if one of the answer choices is a longer answer", "Christchurch", "Wellington", "Auckland"]),
        Question(text: "What is the highest mountain in New Zealand?", options: ["Mount Cook", "Mount Aspiring", "Mount Taranaki"], correctAnswer: "Mount Cook", imageName: UIImage(named: "cherry"), originalOptions: ["Mount Cook", "Mount Aspiring", "Mount Taranaki"]),
    ]
}

class Qmodel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contentSelectedSet: [Question] = []  // <-- here
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isQuizViewShowing = false
    //    @State var contentQuizTitle = ""
    @StateObject var model = Qmodel()  // <-- here
    @State var hasSelectedSet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("MenuView click on this")  // <-- for my testing
                .onTapGesture {
                    model.contentSelectedSet = Question.questionsCore
                    hasSelectedSet = true
                    isQuizViewShowing = true
                }
//            MenuView(onQuizButtonTapped: { menuSelectedSet in
//                contentSelectedSet = menuSelectedSet
//                hasSelectedSet = true
//                print("The content set is \(String(describing: contentSelectedSet))")
//                print("The selected set is \(menuSelectedSet)")
//                isQuizViewShowing = true})
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "book.fill")
                Text("Learn")
            }
            Text("PracticeView")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "chart.bar.fill")
                    Text("Practice")
                }
            Text("SettingsView")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                    Text("Settings")
                }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isQuizViewShowing) {
            if hasSelectedSet {  // <-- here
                DebugQuizView(isPresented: $isQuizViewShowing,
                              selectedSet: model.contentSelectedSet)
            }
            else {
                Text("Selected set is nil") // show a message if selectedSet is nil
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DebugQuizView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State var selectedSet: [Question]
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(selectedSet[1].text)
            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you declared `contentSelectedSet` as `@State` but didn't use it  anywhere in `body`. SwiftUI's dependency tracking feature only calls for `body` when states are set if they are ones that have been previously read in body. You can fix it by forcing a read in `body` like this:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isQuizViewShowing) { [contentSelectedSet] in
```